# Underscores vs Periods within android XML files

Tags: android, xml, naming-conventions

this is my first question on here and I have been looking and can't seem to find the answer, my question is, how does one know when to use underscores versus using periods when referencing within android xml files?

This code for example:

```
android:theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

Uses periods instead of underscores when the actual name of the variable is:

```
Theme_Holo_Light
```

What is the reason for this? Or is it just how android parses the XML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short answer,

Use `periods` in xml,

and use `underscore` when you're referring an id programmatically. For example `mThemeId = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light`

Comment: android:title="@string/action_settings"
Why would you use underscores when referencing strings within xml or other resources? Would it be because you yourself declared the values with underscores rather than variables already declared within Android API?

Comment: @Matrix159 Yes. That's correct. It's the string name you're defining. You can even set your string name as "action.settings". Try it in your strings.xml

Comment: Ok, thank you! I assume using periods with the android API is just how they felt like parsing when the developers created it?